# Powershell Select-Object -Skip and -SkipLast outputs empty file

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I'm trying to use the tree command on a bunch of folders and then trim first 5 lines of text and last 7. However, when I execute the powershell command, the file is empty. Any suggestions?

Here's the code:

```
for /d %%A in (*) do (
    echo %%A
    tree %%A /F /A>"%%A\info\index.txt"
powershell -Command "Get-Content -Path '%%A\info\index.txt' | Select-Object -Skip 5 | Select-Object -SkipLast 7">"%%A\info\index.txt"
    )
```

Cheers.

Comment: Did you check `index.txt` before the powershell command. Can you confirm that it is there, has lines and also have more than 12 lines (since you're taking out the first 5 lines and the last 7 one?

Comment: on  my system, the `tree` command has TWO leading info lines before the 1st data line, and ONE trailing blank line after the last data line ... as `Sage Pourpre` pointed out, your skip combo is likely destroying your data. [*grin*]

Comment: I did check, before the powershell command - it has 410 lines.

Comment: Try `%%~fA` to expand to the full path, may change something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put parentheses around get-content so it completes first before writing to the same file, and use set-content instead of > for the same reason.

```
for /d %%A in (*) do (
    echo %%A
    tree %%A /F /A>"%%A\info\index.txt"
powershell -Command "(Get-Content -Path '%%A\info\index.txt') | Select-Object -Skip 5 | Select-Object -SkipLast 7 | Set-Content %%A\info\index.txt"
    )
```

I would just as soon do the whole thing in powershell:

```
get-childitem -Directory | foreach-object { tree $_ /F /A| select-object -skip 5 | select-object -SkipLast 7 | set-content $_\info\index.txt }
```

With aliases:

```
dir -dir | % { tree $_ /F /A | select -skip 5 | select -SkipLast 7 | set-content $_\info\index.txt }
```